# Cleaner way of binding two related properties

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I have a list of items called GACC, and a list of items called Zone, and 2 dropdowns. When 
the Gacc dropdown is changed, the list of zones in that Gacc changes. The Gacc is a global list that never changes and is set as follows:

```
 var gacclist = (from d in ctx.GACCS
                        select d).Distinct();
        radGACC.ItemsSource = gacclist;
```

I then set the xaml:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Name="radGACC" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" IsEditable="True" SelectedIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="22" />
    <telerik:RadComboBox Name="radZone" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" IsEditable="True" SelectedIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="22" />
```

How can I use binding so that the list of zones in the radZone dropdown automatically displays the zones from the selected gacc? I was going to use an event and change the radZone whenever radGacc changed, but I thought there may be a better way of doing this using some fancy binding. Thanks.

EDIT: One gacc contains many zones, so it is a very simple relationship.

Comment: What is the relation between GACC and Zone?

Comment: One gacc contains many zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Name="radGACC" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" IsEditable="True" SelectedIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="22" />
<telerik:RadComboBox Name="radZone" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" IsEditable="True" SelectedIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="22" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Zones, ElementName=radGACC}"/>
```

> ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Zones, ElementName=radGACC}"

This will Bind the ItemSource to the Zones of Selected GACC . am assuming Zones is the property name of the zones of particular GACC. I hope this will help

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense. Thank you very much!